# Is it recommended to compose WPF pages using smaller components?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it common practice in WPF to create custom controls and use them as page components and directives, similar to how it's done in Angular?

Angular example:

```
<custom:control></custom:control>
<custom:super-bindable-view prop1="{}" prop2={}></custom:super-bindable-view>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to match what I *think* was your intention. If I missed the point, feel free to roll back my edit and try again, because the question was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common practice, but doing so depends on the situation.

Creating sub-controls, either customs controls or user controls, can help to simplify your XAML. It separates the logic for that component so that your view model doesn't have to get unnecessarily bloated. The downside is that you do create extra binding logic by way of dependency properties and it can obfuscate what your view is supposed to be doing.

The main deciding factor is around reusability. If you want to use the same control in multiple places, then it's probably a good idea. Otherwise you need to ask whether or not pulling out a separate control will make your code easier to understand and maintain.